# How to train in models, with efficient inferences, like belief-propagation ?

Tags: machine-learning, inference, graphical-model

There are many papers that are devoted to efficient inference in graphical models. Though many of these paper don't explicitly talk about the learning (training, etc) problem. For example:

http://videolectures.net/mlss09uk_minka_ai/

I am a little confused on how these models being trained. I thought they are probably doing an EM-like algorithm, i.e.

1. Inference  (and calculating all marginals, using VB or EP)
2. Maximizing the likelihood using some blackbox optimization toolboxes using the marginals in the previous case

For example, consider different variants of Belief-Propagation. There are HUGE number of variants for BP, but how a graphical model could be trained?

Any comments?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

BP like methods find the optimal parameters for maximizing posterior. This is basically the parameter estimation. Inference can also be done in a similar way. Prediction of the new label could be cast as maximizing a posterior given the optimal parameters of the new model. This is a fully Bayesian approach to estimation, in contrary to directly doing EM steps. For more details see section 4 @ http://www.eecs.berkeley.edu/~wainwrig/Papers/Wainwright06_JMLR.pdf

Answer (score 1):

I'm a little confused by your question. Tom Minka's tutorial you are referring to is completely devoted to inference in graphical models. Learning the parameters of a graphical model is an inference problem, and, therefore, methods explained in the tutorial such as expectation propagation or variational inference can be applied to it. In fact, all of the examples in the tutorial show how to learn parameters in various graphical models.

EM algorithm can be applied to this problem as well. It should be, however, noted the the EM algorithm delivers point estimates for the parameters of interest, and, therefore, can be inferior to the approximate Bayesian inference methods discussed in the tutorial, since these methods aim to capture all the uncertainty present in the posterior distribution over parameters.

Comment: Oh, I see. I think I was confusing these two: { 
1. Finding the most probable "output label/value" given "input observation" 

2. Finding the most probable "parameters of the model", given pairs of training data.}  By "inference" I usually refer to 1(and "train" refers to 2), but apparently Minka refers to 2, by "inference" (as in inferring the efficient parameters). Right?

Comment: The word 'inference' means finding posterior distribution (not the most probable value!) on some variables of the model, given values of some other variables. Variables of interest can be output labels or model parameters, or latent variables. In Bayesian inference there is no explicit distinction between different kinds of variables.

Comment: @Daniel. In Jordan & Wainwright's book, parameter learning has its own chapter, Chapter 6 called **"Variational Methods in Parameter Estimation"** and they make the distinction between `"EM estimation"` and `"Variational Bayes"` which is the application of message passing methods to parameter learning in a bayesian setting. That said, I think they mention that unfortunately the term **"Variational Bayes"** has been reserved to "mean-field" approximations, even though, you could technically apply other methods such as Expectation Propagation, Bethe-Kikuchi & Sum-Product to parameter estimation

Comment: BTW, one thing I don't understand myself is why **Expectation Propagation** is not seen as an example of **Variational Bayes**. Don't all these models operate in a Bayesian setting using message-passing to approximate the posterior?

Comment: @Josh: First Comment: Agreed. Second commend: As Waingwright explains, "Variational" is an umbrella term for approximations using "functionals". In that sense, EP is indeed a variational approximation.

Comment: @hr0nix: Thanks for the illuminating comment. This filled in an important gap I had in mind! :D 
Just to get more sense of other posterior approximation techniques, do you know any available examples of BP (e.g. on factor-graphs) for parameter estimation?

Comment: @Josh I think that by "Variational Bayes" people usually mean "meal-field approximation", which is different from what EP does. Also I have to note that neither EP nor Variational Bayes imply message passing.

Comment: @Daniel are you asking if I know a probabilistic model where BP has been successfully used to infer model variables which can be interpreted as the parameters of the model? Note that EP includes BP as a special case, so if you've familiarized yourself with EP, you don't need to study BP separately .

Comment: @hr0nix: Yes, I have read Minka's notes and that EP includes BP. The proof is not really trivial, so I prefer not to convince myself with that. Just our of curiosity, can you point me to some work which use BP for model selection?

Comment: @hr0nix (your comment to @Josh): I don't agree. "Mean-field" refers the way people usually factorize their approximate distribution. Though "variational" is a very general name referred to the approximation scheme. "Variational" is extensively used, even in other approximation schemes in other communities.

Comment: @Daniel Thing is, BP is exact, and, therefore, limited to discrete or Gaussian models. That's why it's usually employed when the model parameters are known and some sort of discrete labels need to be inferred. One quite trivial example of using BP to learn model parameters I can think of is inferring mean of a Gaussian with a known precision from a bunch of samples, but it is of little interest.

Comment: @hr0nix: That's weird ...

Comment: @hr0nix: OK, at the same time that BP it is very similar to EP, it is different. So, for BP, given that we have a graphical model with probabilities for observations, and given their parameters,  we can efficiently find marginals, and do prediction. 
Now the question is, given training samples, how can we efficiently learn parameters of the model. In one hand, this is an inference problem, and there are good approximations for that. But the problem is that, the probabilities are defined for observation variables, *not parameters*.

Comment: Continued: In other word, a distribution in our graphical model, is a *proper* distribution, with respect to its variable(s), but not necessarily with respect to all of its parameters. For example, $p \sim N(x|\mu, \Sigma)$, is a defined over x (the random variable), but it is not a proper probability distribution with respect to $\Sigma$ (right?). That makes using BP-like approach, hard (impossible?) for parameter learning problem; since your probabilities are not proper with respect to their unknown parameters(then, the formula for calculating messages, don't hold anymore).

Comment: No, sorry, you got it wrong. It's not that the posterior distribution over parameters does not exist or is improper. It's just that BP is a weak method which can handle very limited number of models only, because it attempts to compute marginals exactly. It can be possible for discrete or Gaussian models, but that's pretty much it. EP, on the other hand, approximates marginals and, therefore, is out of trouble. And in discrete and Gaussian models EP will work exactly as BP.

Comment: ok, agree, it works most efficiently on the "exponential family", where computation of messages is simpler. 

That said, even for exponential family, I still have some doubts. Wherever in Wainwright & Jordan (2008) I read, it is talking about "inference", where the distribution of the target variation is in the exponential family. But this assumption doesn't usually hold for the model parameters. So, his methods won't work for parameter estimation (ignoring the chapter 6 on "variational mean field")

Comment: Continued: So, let's go simple. Say in a graphical model, of Gaussian random variables, how can you perform parameter estimation with BP? Any pointers?

Answer (score 0):

Training is done by EM, repeating the E-step and M-step until convergence.

1. E-step: calculate sufficient statistics using the posterior over the hidden variables given the observed variables.
2. M-step: update the parameters using the sufficient statistics computed in the E-step

For example, see this paper on how it proves learning parameters of HMM is also a belief propagation.
http://homepages.inf.ed.ac.uk/csutton/notes/sutton04fbbp.pdf

Comment: I see your point. This is almost something that I've mentioned in my question body. But what @hr0nix mentioned is more interesting me. As I understand, he is treating training the parameters just like an inference problem.